# Next sibling using mshtml.IHTMLElement

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have a DOM element in a mshtml.IHTMLElement object (Reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  I want to get the DOM element which "naviagable to" by going to the parent element of the one I have then going to the next sibling of that and then getting the 2nd child element of that.

```
mshtml.IHTMLElement ele = document.getElementById("myid"); // the initial DOM element
ele.parentElement.????? // can get to parent, but what do I use to get to the next sibling
```

There is no nextsibling method (or similar) in the context sensitive popup.

There is an "all" property, but nothing (except dynamically worked out options at runtime) for all, so don't know what to use.

How do I get to the next sibling and then to the 2nd child of that?

I notice that the documentation for this interface makes no mention of the "children" property, but the popup has one on offer, so I wonder if there are other things available that will get me to the next sibling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out in the end - probably not the most elegant way, but it works:

```
((IHTMLDOMNode)document.getElementById("myid").parentElement).nextSibling.childNodes[1]
```

casting it to IHTMLDOMNode gives me a nextsibling option